# accessing file saved to device writeToFile

Tags: ios, writetofile, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm saving my UITextView text into a file, test.txt

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
[self.textBox.text writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSLog(path);
```

This works fine on the mac in the simulator, as it provides a library and I can just click on it to open the txt file. However, on the iPad, I"m not sure how to do this.

```
/var/mobile/Applications/10AC319A-D567-4DC6-B7C9-E53E71B82B89/Documents/test.txt
```

is where i'ts stored. I'm guessing the documents folder can't be accessed via ipad?

How do I pull this document within the app? Or save it in the app so that the user of the app can access it ?

Aside from the save button, I have another button called Read which should pull up test.txt somehow

I've started with

```
 -(IBAction)readAssignment:(id)sender{

    NSString* GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); {
        static NSString* documentsDirectory = nil;
        if (documentsDirectory == nil) {
            documentsDirectory = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];}

        self.textBox.text= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];
    }

}




self.textBox.text= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];
```

returns the file path, but how do i get it so that it displays the text.txt text that is saved into the textview?

But I know this isn't working/right.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you're running on the device?

Comment: @JoshCaswell when I run on the mac, it creates a folder  /Users/vchang/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Documents/test.txt  where I can access it. Howeve, when I run it on the device, I'm not sure where to access the created document test.txt. I want the user to be able to pull up the saved document later on

Comment: You mean outside the application? Each iOS app has its own Documents directory; other apps can't access it.

Comment: Hm how do I access this directory or pull up test.txt within the app? I know it can save it but I'm unsure how to pull it up in the app... I created a new button that is supposed to do this, and I'll add that portion but I know i'ts wrong.

Comment: Just read it in at the same path you wrote it to: `[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];`

Comment: return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell and jeremyw, I did both of these and changed it in my edit above. However, when I want to print this saved text in my textview, it displays the file path not the text. Also, I didn't use return because I got an error saying that my method could not have a return! 

Why isn't it displaying the text that is saved, instead of the file path?

Comment: ah nevermind i just figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NSString`'s `stringWithContentsOfFile` method, you can read back the text from a file.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
[self.textBox.text writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"myText: %@", myText);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for! I had to change some things to reprint the saved text to my textBox but overall this worked

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get the files, outside your application, you can use the below solution.

If you are storing the file in `documents directory`, you can access the file via `iTunes`.

For that you need to enable the `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the `info.plist` of your application.

Then connect to iTunes -> Sync the application -> Click on your app in iTunes, you can see the files

Comment: Thank you @midhun MP!
However, I was looking for a way to read it in the application instead of on iTunes. But I will keep this in mind for future reference.